# How can I predict sequences of tuple using RNNs?

Tags: python, sequence, prediction, recurrent-neural-network

How can I predict sequences of tuple using RNNs?

The question is as follows:
1. There is a number set: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...n}. 
2. Arbitrary subset can be extracted from the set. For example:(2,3,4)
3. How to predict the sequences like ((1,2),(3,4),(2,3),(3,4,5),...,(a,b,c,d))

We map elements in sequence to vectors,(e.g. (1,2)->(0.5,0.5,0,0,0,...,0)), and attempt to process this problem in RNNs. But we found it difficult to implement BPTT(back propagation through time).

How to design my RNN model?